# Is this correct and good way to express?

Tags: sentence-construction, tense

I am off to work on my Monday morning as I was at my brother's wedding. I will resume work on Tuesday.

How about this way?

I attended my brother's wedding yesterday, and I am on the way to my home town. I will reach home by Monday evening and resume work on Tuesday.

Comment: I think you mean you are off work (without to), as this means be absent.  Try this: I attended my brother's wedding yesterday, and now I am returning to my home town. I will reach home by Monday evening and resume work on Tuesday.

Comment: It's just *...on Monday morning*, not *...on **my** Monday morning*. Also, as @BruceMurray says, you're just *off work* (having "a day off"), not *off **to** work* (about to start the journey to work).